# Creating a function inside a useEffect() vs importing it from another file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, optimization, memory

At work, I've stumbled upon a code like this

```
function Component({ data }) {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(0);
    const [angle, setAngle] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const updateValues = (newValue, check, setter) => {
            if (check) {        
                setter(newValue):
            } else {
                setter(null):       
            }
        };
        updateValues(10, true, setNumber);
        updateValues(20, false, setSpeed);
        updateValues(30, true, setAngle);
    }, [data]);

    // ...
}
```

Here, we can see that the useEffect() has a function within it called updateValues() that does multiple state updates. I have been told to export this function into another file for Performance issues.

```
// file1.js
export const updateValues = (newValue, check, setter) => {
            if (check) {        
                setter(newValue):
            } else {
                setter(null):       
            }
        };

// Component.js

import { updateValues } from "file1.js";

function Component({ data }) {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(0);
    const [angle, setAngle] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        updateValues(10, true, setNumber);
        updateValues(20, false, setSpeed);
        updateValues(30, true, setAngle);
    }, [data]);

    // ...
}
```

I've been wondering if something like this really an issue in React ? [The official React documentation](https://react.dev/) has multiple example of functions within useEffect() and close to no mention of garbage collection. I'm wondering if an imported function would be correctly destroyed by the Garbage Collection and at the appropriate time.

My hypothesis is that importing a function or anything else creates something in memory that is still there even though we don't need it.

I'm not sure if this question is an "opinion-based" question, because I'm just looking for an explanation about how memory and garbage collection work inside useEffect().

Comment: There is no significant difference in performance between the two (it there is any)

Comment: Are you sure you was told because of performance?, as that's just a none issue here, but if it's because of code re-usability I can understand that.   In either case the garbage collector has no influence..

Comment: Yes, the people that told me think that "updateValues()" will be recreated each time useEffect() is called, but only one time when it is imported

Comment: Yes It will get re-created every time data changes, but for such a small function I very much doubt it would make much difference.  Unless that code was going to get re-used, it's not something I would do anyway, talking of the GC by putting into another file the function will never be GC'ed, so in theory will take more memory, but again it's really splitting hairs here.. :)

Comment: @Keith thanks for your input, I would validate your answer if I could :D

Answer (score 0):

The reason you've been advised to do this is because your [useEffect is created every time your component's code runs](https://medium.com/codex/everything-you-thought-you-knew-about-react-functional-components-is-wrong-baf2dfc4f6f)--which can be more often than it renders. All this stuff isn't used 90% of the time that it's made, so it's being created and garbage collected for nothing. So the more stuff you can move outside your component, the better. It matters less if an imported function (or one you simply create outside your functional component) is garbage collected, because it is only created the one time, whereas anything you define in your component is created hundreds or thousands of times.

Honestly, your function and its usage is kinda weird. I'm assuming it's just pseudo-code, because if not, your useEffect function body would be better like this

```
setNumber(10);
setSpeed(null);
setAngle(30);
```

Also, consider using useReducer, which lends itself to having the function defined outside the component in a way developers may understand better.